# How to see which files contain in Fedora package installed?

Tags: package-management, fedora

How to see which files contain in Fedora package installed? For example, I have package `tigervnc-server` installed on `Fedora release 15 (Lovelock)` and want to see how it differs from distriburion of official TigerVNC site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list the files contained in a package with the `rpm` command.  For example:

```
# rpm -ql tigervnc-server
/etc/sysconfig/vncservers
/lib/systemd/system/vncserver@.service
/usr/bin/vncserver
/usr/bin/x0vncserver
/usr/share/man/man1/vncserver.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/x0vncserver.1.gz
```